# web3.js 0.20.7 & Metamask: contract.setProvider(web3.givenProvider) is not a function

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am interacting with a contract on the Rinkeby testnet using web3.js (version 0.20.7) with Metamask and the chrome console.

I setup a contract object called mycontract for a given ABI and address.
When I set the web3 provider for this contract using mycontract.setProvider(web3.givenProvider) I get an error saying that mycontract.setProvider is not a function.

See below the js code deployed in the chrome console:

```
> const mycontract = web3.eth.contract(ABI, Address);
undefined
> mycontract.setProvider(web3.givenProvider);
< VM212:1 Uncaught TypeError: simpleStorage.setProvider is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

I suppose this may be due to the fact that the `mycontract.setProvider(web3.givenProvider)` command is for web3.js version 1.0 and above.
However, if it is the case, I could not find info about what command I should use with web3.js 0.20.7.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Please `console.log(web3.version)` inside your code and report back with the result.

Comment: Here is what I am getting:  ```> console.log(web3.version)

> {api: "0.20.7", getNode: ƒ, getNetwork: ƒ, …} VM288:1``` So as expected it seems to be the version 0.20.7 of web3.js. Do you know what should I do to execute the code described in my post above? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
> const mycontract = web3.eth.contract(ABI, Address);
undefined
```

Indicates a problem in `web3.eth.contract(ABI, Address)`, right?

You've printed `web3.version` and got `0.20.7`, right?

So now you need to open the documentation of web3.js v0.x, and check again what it says about `web3.eth.contract` (right?).

If you open it ([here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract)), then you can understand from the coding example that instead of doing this:

```
const mycontract = web3.eth.contract(ABI, Address);
```

You should be doing this:

```
const mycontract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(Address);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the link to the example. I followed the example closely and could resolve my problems.FYI to set the web3 provider I did ```web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)``` (instead of ```mycontract.setProvider(web3.givenProvider)```) and it worked.